# How to encrypt user data on the backend but allow for data sharing amongst users?

Tags: security, encryption, private-key

I was wondering what was the preferred way to encrypt user data in a database with a user-specific key but allow for data sharing between users.

The database owner should not be able to decrypt the data, only the users sharing the file.

I can only see one possible solution that allows all users to modify the data:

When user data become "shared", it changes from a single-user mode to a multiple-user mode and a data-specific key is produced and shared amongst the users. The key will only be used for that particular data.

Is this a valid approach ?

Are there better ways to do that ?

Answer (score -1):

Why not just share the (user-specific) key with the user's friends.

If you don't want the key (for short, USK) disclosed to others. You may compute USK' from Hash(USK || the data), and share USK' to friends.